# ES6 function parameter

Tags: javascript

I recently picked up a book called Javascript Allonge for learning the language. And I'm struggling at certain chapters and topics.

```
const foldWith = (fn, terminalValue, [first, ...rest]) =>
first === undefined
? terminalValue
: fn(first, foldWith(fn, terminalValue, rest));
```

Now, I understand ES6 function declaration, calling or invoking, but I'm confused by the fact `foldWith` gets called with more "inner parameters". In the next code:

```
foldWith((number, rest) => number * number + rest, 0, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

I can't seem to figure out how `foldWith((number, rest)` `number` and `rest` here gets decided what part of parameter they are? I mean `foldWith` function created with 4 parameters and called with 4 but how `number` gets linked to `first` and `rest` to `rest`?

Comment: I'm not surprised that function throws you as a beginner! It's fairly complex. :-)

Comment: See [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: Yeah it actually just takes 3 parameters with the last one being destructured from a single list argument into a list's first element & "the rest" of the list. This pattern is common in functional languages: you take one element, process it, and then recursively call the same function on the rest of the list, so that the next call takes the second element (the first of "the rest") in that destructuring expression

Comment: Like I get it in mapWith function:
    const mapWith = (fn, [first, ...rest]) =>
    first === undefined
    ? []
    : [fn(first), ...mapWith(fn, rest)];
    mapWith((x) => x * x, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

mapWith created with fn , and array([first, ...rest]) and gets called in the same fashion but not with foldWith.

Comment: Try to understand what `let [first, ...rest] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` does. If you get that, then you'll get how these parameters get their values. It's all about destructuring assignment.

Comment: @rakib.h Not quite sure where your confusion is. `foldWith` gets called with the same kinds of arguments recursively as it is called initially, just without the `first` element of the passed array; that’s exactly what `mapWith` gets called with, too — just without the `terminalValue`, because that doesn’t apply to `mapWith`. Could you [edit] your question and point out the difference you perceive between `mapWith` and `foldWith`?

Comment: Maybe also be aware of the difference between the `foldWith` function and the `fn` (callback) function. They are different. One gets 3 arguments, the other is called back with 2 arguments. Not to be confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foldWith` is a recursive function (it calls itself sometimes) using parameter destructuring. The destructuring is here:

```
const foldWith = (fn, terminalValue, [first, ...rest]) =>
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That takes the third argument it receives, which is an array in the example call, and:

- Extracts the first element from the array into the parameter `first`, and
- Extracts all the other elements from the array into a new array it puts in the parameter `rest`.

This is called *iterable destructuring* (sometimes people call it "array destructuring" but it's not limited to arrays).

For the first call, the array is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, so `first` gets `1` and `rest` gets a new array with `[2, 3, 4, 5]`.

So that's that part. Next, the recursion. Let's look at the function again (with some added formatting):

```
const foldWith = (fn, terminalValue, [first, ...rest]) =>
    first === undefined
        ? terminalValue
        : fn(first, foldWith(fn, terminalValue, rest));
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−− recursive call
```

`foldWith` calls itself. Initially, it's called with `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` as the third argument, so:

- In the top call, `first` is `1` (not `undefined`) and `rest` is `[2, 3, 4, 5]`. Since `first` is not `undefined`, `foldWith` calls itself with `[2, 3, 4, 5]` as part of `fn(first, foldWith(fn, terminalValue, rest))`:

  - During that call, `first` is `2` and `rest` is `[3, 4, 5]`, so it calls itself again as part of `fn(first, foldWith(fn, terminalValue, rest))`:

    - During that call, `first` is `3` and `rest` is `[4, 5]`, so it calls itself again as part of `fn(first, foldWith(fn, terminalValue, rest))`:

      - During that call, `first` is `4` and `rest` is `[5]`, so it calls itself again as part of `fn(first, foldWith(fn, terminalValue, rest))`:

        - During that call, `first` is `5` and `rest` is `[]`, so it calls itself again as part of `fn(first, foldWith(fn, terminalValue, rest))`:

          - During that call, `first` is `undefined` (because if you try to get the first element from an empty array, you get `undefined`) and `rest` is `[]`. So `foldWith` **doesn't** call itself. Instead, it returns the value `terminalValue`.
        - The rest of `fn(first, foldWith(fn, terminalValue, rest))` can now be done, with `terminalValue` where the `foldWith` call was. So it's effectively `fn(first, terminalValue)`; it returns that result.
      - That result is now used in `fn(first, <<previous result>>)` and that result is returned
    - Same again, that result is now used in `fn(first, <<previous result>>)` and that result is returned
  - Same again
- The call returns the final result from `fn`.

Let's try to visualize that:

```js
let indent = 0;
function log(...msgs) {
    console.log(`${"  ".repeat(indent)}${msgs.join(" ")}`);
}
const foldWith = (fn, terminalValue, [first, ...rest]) => {
    log(`foldWith(fn, ${terminalValue}, ${first === undefined ? "[]" : JSON.stringify([first, ...rest])})`);
    // log(first === undefined ? `* Returning ${terminalValue}` : `Recursing`);
    ++indent;
    const result = first === undefined
        ? terminalValue
        : fn(first, foldWith(fn, terminalValue, rest));
    --indent;
    log(`foldWith returning ${result}`);
    return result;
};

const fn = (number, rest) => {
    const result = number * number + rest;
    log(`fn(${number}, ${rest}) is ${result}`);
    return result;
}
const final = foldWith(fn, 0, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
log(`Final result: ${final}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I go into destructuring in detail in Chapter 7 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer ! It seems to sinking in. Now im going to run the code couple of times till i get it ;p

Comment: could give it a try!!